# how to match keys from nested associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

so for example i have something like

```
array:2 [▼
  "old" => array:2 [▼
    "uk" => "unk"
    "en" => "eng"
    "fr" => "fre"
  ]
  "new" => array:2 [▼
    "uk" => "united kingdom"
    "en" => "english"
    "fr" => "french"
  ]
]
```

atm i can only get one item according to a predefined key

```
foreach ($data as $status => $value) {
    $str .= $value['uk'];
}
```

which give

```
unk    united kingdom
```

instead i want to get all of them, so the result would be

```
unk    united kingdom
eng    english
fre    french
```

which could be translated into an array or combined values

```
array:3 [▼
  "uk" => [
    "unik",
    "united kingdom"
  ],
  "en" => [
    "eng",
    "english"
  ],
  "fr" => [
    "fren",
    "french"
  ]
]
```

so what's the best way to achive that ?

Comment: `$code` is an array or a string?

Comment: @hassan a string

Comment: @KrisRoofe not sure what u r after., $code is predefined, i updated the post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may go with [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) as follows:

```
$output = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($value, $key) use (&$output) {
    $output[$key][] = $value;
});
```

live example: https://3v4l.org/aKYsG .

Comment: focken legend, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You just need to flatten the sub-arrays :

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data as $status => $codeArray) {
   foreach ($codeArray as $code=>$value){
     $output[$code][]=$value;
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanx.